# Получить доступ к переменной родительского класса PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

Есть класс подключения к дб:

```
class DataBase {

    public static $db = null;
    public $msqli;

    public static function getDb() {
        if (self::$db == null) {
            self::$db = new DataBase();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

    private function __construct() {
        $this->msqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'depsoft');

    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if ($this->msqli) {
            $this->msqli->close();
        }
    }
}
```

Есть наследующий от него класс в другом файле, выполняющий некие другие функции:

```
require_once "connect.php";
class DateFormToInsert extends DataBase {

    public static function dateFromToInsert() {

        $query_user = mysqli_query($this->msqli, "SELECT * FROM `region_table`");
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_user, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
    }
}

$aa = DateFormToInsert::getDb();
DateFormToInsert::dateFromToInsert();
```

Верен ли такой подход? До этого я не пробовал писать на ооп. И второй вопрос - как в дочернем классе получить доступ к $this->msqli, определенной в родителе ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала по первому классу.

1. `public static $db = null;` должно быть `private`, раз уж вы синглтон делаете и отдаете его методом
2. Деструктор тут, в принципе, не особо нужен. mysqlnd самостоятельно закрывает соединения по окончанию работы скрипта
3. Зачем вам такой странный подход с `$db` и `$mysqli`? Не лучше ли по `getDb` сразу отдавать ресурс коннекта к БД (и инициализировать его, если надо)?
4. В `getDb` хорошо бы вставить обработку ошибок коннекта, чтобы не отдавать `false` или `null` туда, где их не ожидают
5. Это уже вкусовщина, но я бы использовал `PDO`, а не `mysqli`

Теперь по второму классу.

Нет, так делать не стоит, поскольку у этих двух классов очень разные ответственности. Это как наследовать дедушку от лопаты, потому, что они оба старенькие.

А надо так

```
$query_user = mysqli_query(Database::getDb(), "SELECT * FROM `region_table`");
```

Тут у вас `DataBase` будет провайдером зависимости для `DateFormToInsert`

Answer (score 0):

```
class DB
{
    private static $_instance = null;

    // для безопасности настройки лучше хранить в файле с конфигом
    private static DB_HOST = '';
    private static DB_NAME = '';
    private static DB_USER = '';
    private static DB_PASS = '';

    private function __construct () {

        $this->_instance = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=' . self::DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . self::DB_NAME,
            self::DB_USER,
            self::DB_PASS,
            [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"]
        );

    }

    private function __clone () {}
    private function __wakeup () {}

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$_instance != null) {
            return self::$_instance;
        }

        return new self;
    }
}


require_once "connect.php";
class DateFormToInsert  {

    public static function dateFromToInsert() {

        $db = DB::getInstance();

        $query_user = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `region_table`")->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще то он и так синглтон.

Comment: Ну вообще да, и так синглтон. А как его правильно использовать в другом файле? И вообще,что как изменить что бы пробраться таки к переменной $msqli ?

Comment: вообще то не полноценный, так как его можно клонировать

Comment: Неполноценный потому что я меняю области доступа, так как не могу решить проблему. А так там все было private

Comment: за что у вас отвечает класс new DataBase() ?

Comment: По идеи - за создание объекта дб

Comment: исправил свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

$query_user = mysqli_query(DataBase::getDb()->msqli, "SELECT * FROM `region_table`");